# Virtual filesystem backed up by key-value database

Tags: key-value-store, vfs

I am looking for an existing virtual filesystem implementation that stores its data in key-value database. (I was not able to find much as internet is crowded by key-value databases backed up by filesystem.)

I would like to avoid creating it, together with Java bindings and userland tools to access/mount it to ensure decent integration with external tools. Is there any such project? If there is not, is it such a bad idea?

Thanks for any pointers.

---

Context: I want to migrate existing application away from FS backend. And as it is not realistic to rewrite all relevant code, I am looking for a way to fake filesystem for the application entirely.

Answer (score 0):

One candidate seems to be [Grid FS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) with its [Java bindings](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html) and [gridfs-fuse](https://github.com/Imroy/gridfs-fuse) for mounting.